# Explain intuition for probability is wrong?

Tags: probability, intuition

I'd like to calculate the probability of a domino player drawing 6 doubles out of 7 dominoes drawn.

My instincts wants to do the following to calculate:

There are 7 doubles and 21 nondoubles in a domino set of 28.

So...

$$
\frac{7}{28} \frac{6}{27} \frac{5}{26}\frac{4}{25}\frac{3}{24}\frac{2}{23}\frac{21}{22}
$$

Which generalizes to
$$
\frac{7!}{(7-k)!}\frac{21!}{(21-7+k)!}\frac{(28-7)!}{28!}
$$
Where k is amount of doubles.

This incorrectly produces an answer that's a factor of  $${7 \choose k}$$ from the - I believe - correct answer, as shown below:

There are 7 ways to have 6 doubles  with an extra domino that can be any 21.

So...

$$
\frac{{7 \choose 6}*{21 \choose 1}}{{28 \choose 7}}
$$

Which generalizes to

$$
\frac{{7 \choose k}*{21 \choose 7-k}}{{28 \choose 7}} 
$$

Or

$$
\frac{7!}{((k)!(7-k)!)} \frac{21!}{((21-7+k)!(7-k)!)} \frac{(28-7)!7!}{(28!)}
$$

I'd like to understand intuitively why $${7 \choose k}$$ is needed? Is it simply because each domino is different? Would things be different if instead of 21 unique dominoes it's 21 of the same domino?

Comment: Do you mean drawing exactly $6$ doubles or drawing at least $6$ doubles?

Comment: Exactly $6$ would be $\binom 76\times \binom {21}1\big/ \binom {28}7$.  At least $6$ would be that plus $1\big/ \binom {28}7$.

Comment: If you want to pick k doubles, then you need to make two decisions: how to get k doubles out of 7 (7 choose k), and how to get 7-k nondoubles out of 21 (21 choose 7-k). The Fundamental Counting Principle says to multiply these two numbers to get the number of ways to make the pair of decisions.

Comment: Your attempt appears to specify an order...That is, you first choose $6$ doubles and then you choose a non-double. But of course that's a different question.

Comment: Thanks for the replies.  I meant drawing exactly 6. In my head because it's all commutative all numerators can swap places and it would still be the same math so I figured order didn't matter. @J.Chapman would this apply even if the nondoubles were the same domino 21 times?

Comment: @anthonygonzalez I'm not sure what you mean by the same domino 21 times. Don't we have 28 distinct dominos to start with?

Comment: @J.Chapman normally yes. I was setting a game where instead of 21 unique dominos left you had the 1 domino copied 21 times. For example, you have all doubles (0-0, 1-1,... 6-6, and then the rest of the dominos would be 0-1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So...

> $$
> \frac{7}{28} \frac{6}{27} \frac{5}{26}\frac{4}{25}\frac{3}{24}\frac{2}{23}\frac{21}{22}
> $$

This is correct, except that it happens to express the exact probability of drawing the 6 doubles and one non-double, under the assumption that the non-double is drawn last.

The computation is off by a factor of $~7~$ because
the non-double can be drawn in any of the $~7~$ draws.

So, the correct answer is

$$ 7 \times 
\frac{7}{28} \frac{6}{27} \frac{5}{26}\frac{4}{25}\frac{3}{24}\frac{2}{23}\frac{21}{22}. \tag1 $$

---

The more customary method of attack, that arrives at the same computation as that in (1) above, is to use combinatorics.

Express the answer as $~\dfrac{N}{D},~$ where $~N~$ represents the number of combinations of $~7~$ dominoes, which contain exactly $~6~$ doubles, and $~D~$ represent the total number of ways of selecting any $~7~$ dominoes, from the $~28~$ dominoes.

Note that in the previous paragraph, the computations of both $~N,~$ and $~D~$ assume that order of selection is irrelevant.  Such an assumption is permitted in a combinatorics attack on a probability problem, as long as it is consistently applied (i.e. to both $~N~$ and $~D$).

Here, $~\displaystyle N = \binom{7}{6} \times \binom{21}{1},~$ because you have to determine which 6 doubles out of the 7 will be selected, and you have to determine which non-double, out of the 21 will be selected.

Then, $~\displaystyle D = \binom{28}{7},~$ which represents the number of different ways that 7 dominoes can be selected out of 28 dominoes.

Putting this all together, you have that the probability is

$$\frac{\binom{7}{6} \times \binom{21}{1}}{\binom{28}{7}}$$

$$= \frac{7!}{6! \times 1!} \times \frac{21!}{1! \times 20!} \times \frac{7! \times 21!}{28!}$$

$$= 7 \times 21 \times 7! \times \frac{21!}{28!}$$

$$= 7 \times 21 \times \frac{7!}{28 \times 27 \times \cdots \times 22}. \tag2 $$

The expression in (2) above is equivalent to the expression in (1) above.